# Installing multiple apps in Arc Welder in the same context

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc, androidappsonchromeos

Installing Androids apps on Chrome OS with Arc Welder is pretty straight forward and most apps works fine.

However, apps are installed in their own isolated environment and are thus not able to interact with each other.

For example, I have installed both [Total Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander) and the accompanying [FTP Plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.tcplugins.FTP) but TC is not able to see or use the plugin. And if I use TC's virtual folder `Installed apps` which shows all the installed apps, I only see TC itself even though I have several apps installed.

So clearly, each apps is isolated from all other apps.

Is there any way to install multiple apps in the same context so they can interact with each other?

Answer (score 0):

Use Android app intent to communicate between apps. You can trigger an activity from your app to be started in a separate app. You can also get the result back from that app when the activity has finished.

For more info please have a look at [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html)

Comment: This won't work. And it is not what I am asking for. It's not about my own apps, but about any two (or more) apps. Each apps is effectively sandboxed so it's is not possible to send intents between them. It's more like have each app on different phones. My question is if is possible somehow to avoid this, perhaps using the `Additional metadata` field.